# SQL SELECT Query: "Ambiguous column name"

Tags: sql-server

I have never written anything but basic SQL queries. I am trying to join two tables and I am getting this error :

> *Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>
>   Ambiguous column name 'UserId'.*

This is my SQL query :

```
SELECT UserName, UserId
FROM aspnet_Users 
JOIN aspnet_UsersInRoles ON aspnet_Users.UserId = aspnet_UsersInRoles.UserId
```

And this is my database diagram:

[image]

What is wrong with my query?

Also could anyone tell how should I structure this query in order to get the `UserName` and `RoleName`?

Comment: Try running through some tutorials before jumping into SQL: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must specify the table name when using multiple tables since `UserId` appears in both tables.

Assuming you want `UserName` and `UserId` from `aspnet_users`:

```
SELECT aspnet_Users.UserName, aspnet_Users.UserId
FROM aspnet_Users JOIN aspnet_UsersInRoles 
ON aspnet_Users.UserId = aspnet_UsersInRoles.UserId
```

Answer (score 1):

The parser is confused with `UserID` of which table you want to use. `UserID` is coming from two tables and you need to choose which one you want to display

```
SELECT 
    au.UserName , 
    au.UserId
FROM aspnet_Users au 
     JOIN aspnet_UsersInRoles ur
     ON au.UserId = ur.UserId
```

Now we have specified that the one from `aspnet_Users` should be picked. You can still use table name instead of the alias (e.g. au, ur) I used. I prefer them because they are shorter

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT UserName , aspnet_Users.UserId
FROM aspnet_Users JOIN aspnet_UsersInRoles 
ON aspnet_Users.UserId = aspnet_UsersInRoles.UserId
```