# "Ambiguous column name" when joining tables

Tags: sql-server

I'm having difficulty in pulling the userID from joining these two tables.

My goal is to find all vacation balance over 200 and all active userID but I keep getting an ambiguous column name for userID.

My query does work if i try to pull anything else, but I want to pull UserID instead. Any help on my query will be appreciated.

**Here is my table and its columns:** 
Table **USER**

```
ID (PK)
UserID
Firstname
Lastname
Email
Active (Bool)
```

Table **Balance**

```
UserID (PK)
VacationBalance
```

**Here is my Query:**

```
SELECT UserID FROM dbo.VacBal as I join dbo.User as T
on I.userid = T.userid 
WHERE VacationBalance > 200 and active = 1
```

**Here is the error I'm getting:**

> Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Ambiguous column name 'userid'.

Comment: Read the error message. Use `T.UserID` *or* `I.UserID` in the select output to remove the ambiguity (SQL Server doesn't care if they are the same value).

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL SELECT query ambiguous column name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13612135/sql-select-query-ambiguous-column-name)

Answer (score 13):

Because each table contains a `UserID` column, you need to specify from which you want the `UserID` to come by including the table alias in the `SELECT` statement:

```
       v
SELECT T.UserID FROM dbo.VacBal as I join dbo.User as T
on I.userid = T.userid 
WHERE VacationBalance > 200 and active = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT T.UserID 
FROM dbo.VacBal as I 
join dbo.User as T
on I.userid = T.userid 
WHERE VacationBalance > 200 and active = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason behind you getting this error is when you join two or more tables then it will comes up with a common recordset to the select while there are more than one column having the same name so the system is unable to understand which value you want to put there, that's why system generates ambiguity in column name error message.

To avoid this error, make sure that you prefix the column name with the table name or table alias for those columns that exist in more than 1 table. Here’s an updated SELECT statement that will not generate the error:

```
SELECT 
    T.UserID 
FROM dbo.VacBal as I 
    join dbo.User as T on I.userid = T.userid 
WHERE VacationBalance > 200 and active = 1
```

It is a good practice to always prefix column names with the table name or table alias so that in case additional columns are added to a table that have the same name as existing columns in another table, you won’t encounter this error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT UserID
  FROM dbo.VacBal AS I JOIN dbo.User AS T
         USING(userid)
 WHERE VacationBalance > 200 AND active = 1
```